# How to protect built-in el files from being accidentally edited on Windows

Tags: emacs

On Linux, the built-in el files are all read-only, so no problem.

But on MS Windows, what happens is like this:

- I get curious about the definition of the command *isearch-forward*, so I type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd>`f isearch-forward` and click on the link `isearch.el` from the help to get to the definition of the function.
- While I am reading its definition, I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> many times, but I have previously set <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as another Ctrl key, so sometimes it happens that I release <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> too early, in which case <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> becomes inserting `h` or `c`.
- Sometimes I notice that and undo it, but sometimes I don't notice it, and I even save them all with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>`s`.

What is a good way to protect the built-in el files from me on MS Windows?

Comment: Break your habit of periodically pressing C-x s.  Once that's done, you won't have this issue because you won't be subconsciously trying to save random files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the permissions to be read-only.

```
M-x find-function isearch-forward RET
M-x dired RET
% m . RET
M -w RET
```

The sequence will open up the file `isearch.el`, then use dired on its directory.  At which point you mark all the files, and then change permissions to be read only.

You'll also want to do it for the sub directories.  So whip up a macro and run it until you're done.

Starting in the `lisp` dired buffer (the one you created up there), go to the first file (right below `.` and `..`), and begin:

```
C-x (
>
RET
% m . RET
M -w RET
q
C-x )
```

There, you have defined a macro to go to the next directory, enter it, mark all its files read only, and leave the directory.  Now run it several times (20 for Emacs 23.1).

```
C-u 20 C-x e RET
```

And you're done.

If you have a cygwin shell, it'd be a lot easier to just do

```
M-x shell
cd c:/Program\ Files/emacs-23.1/lisp/
chmod -R -w .
```

Comment: in a cmd.exe prompt, cd to the \emacs\lisp directory, and `find -name "*.el" -exec attrib +R {} ;`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Directory Local Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Directory-Local-Variables.html).  This should meet your need:

```
(dir-locals-set-class-variables
 'read-only '((nil (buffer-read-only . t))))
(dir-locals-set-directory-class
 source-directory 'read-only)
```

Change `source-directory` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to make el source buffers read only (using the variable buffer-read-only) on load.

```
(defun my-make-some-read-only ()
  (if (and buffer-file-name
       (or
        (string-match-p "/emacs/lisp/" buffer-file-name)
        (string-match-p "/EmacsW32/lisp/" buffer-file-name)))
      (setq buffer-read-only t)))
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-make-some-read-only)
```

If the above code is in dotemacs, buffers from el files like following are set as read only.

```
c:/Program Files/Emacs/emacs/lisp/emacs-lisp/lisp-mode.el
c:/Program Files/Emacs/EmacsW32/lisp/w32shell.el
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a cmd.exe prompt, and do this:

```
c:\> cd \emacs\lisp
c:\emacs\lisp> find -name "*.el" -exec attrib +R {} ;
```

You need a find.exe utility.  I use the one from [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).